# Adding admob above of gameview

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

guys!

I want to add admob above of game view, but my ad cuts game view and draw black background.

I tried a lot of ways, changed params of layout, but nothing worked, Grateful to anyone who could help me and I can not find a way to make this work, I am frustrated and all applications I have it as looking. The code is taken from the github of libgdx changed a bit to my liking and I have also tried to let it default, but it looks like now. Hope you can help me and sorry for repeating some things. thanks for watch it.

and sorry for my bad english

mine:https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2IJa.png
I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnUSx.jpg

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    adView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(adView);
    View gameView = createGameView(config);
    layout.addView(gameView);

    setContentView(layout);
    startAdvertising(adView);
}

private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

private AdView createAdView() {
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(SMALL_CODE);
        adView.setId(12345); // this is an arbitrary id, allows for relative positioning in createGameView()
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        adView.setLayoutParams(params);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        return adView;
}

private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new MainClass(new RequestAd(adView)), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
    params.bottomMargin = 0;
    params.topMargin = 0;
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second image ( the one you want) the ad is shown below the game view so just change the adview and game views' params as follows:

```
private AdView createAdView() {
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(SMALL_CODE);
        adView.setId(12345); // this is an arbitrary id, allows for relative positioning in createGameView()
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        adView.setLayoutParams(params);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        return adView;
}

private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new MainClass(new RequestAd(adView)), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, adView.getId());
    params.bottomMargin = 0;
    params.topMargin = 0;
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but doesn't works. Now the ad is not showing.

Comment: Try setting the background color to transparent - adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

Comment: So is the image you posted "mine:http://i.imgur.com/06kUSHF.png" your screenshot. I thought the ad was already showing in that image and you were only interested in positioning the ad.

Comment: Yes, I want delete black background and show the ad above of game view like other screenshot.

Comment: You can't delete the background color. You'd have to set a height of your game's view port that allows the ad to take the space above.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I want ad like the second screenshot, but I can't do it. I wanna put ad above of game view without black background that resizes game screen. You know?

Answer (score 0):

change the view first and adview to second as given below in onCreate

```
View gameView = createGameView(config);
layout.addView(gameView);
AdView admobView = createAdView();
layout.addView(admobView);

private AdView createAdView() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId("Your ad id");
    adView.setId(12345);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return adView;
}

private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new Home(this), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
}
```